# Show that $a(XY)=X(aY)$ where $a$ is an element of field and $X$ and $Y$ are $m\times n$ and $n\times p$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $a(XY)=X(aY)$ where $a$ is an element of field and $X$ and $Y$ are $m\times n$ and $n\times p$  matrices.

Comment: An idea for how to approach this problem on your own: start by showing that this is true for an easy but non-trivial case, such as $m=n=p=2$.  In order to make that initial proof work in general, rewrite the statements involved in summation notation (i.e. with a $\sum$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 2):

By using the notation to designate the coefficient of the $i$th row and $j$th column of a matrix $A$: $(A)_{i,j}$, we have

$$(a(XY))_{i,j}=a\cdot (XY)_{i,j}.$$

On the other hand,

\begin{align}
(X(aY))_{i,j} & =\sum_{k=1}^{n} (X)_{i,k} (aY)_{k,j}
\\ & =\sum_{k=1}^{n} (X)_{i,k}\  a\cdot(Y)_{k,j}
\\ & = a\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n} (X)_{i,k} (Y)_{k,j} = a\cdot(XY)_{i,j}.
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Matrix multiplication $\pi:(X,Y)\mapsto XY$ is linear in each slot. By definition $X(aY) = \pi(X,aY)$, which by linearity in the second slot equals $a \pi (X,Y)  = a (X Y)$. Hence $a(X Y) = X(aY)$.

Comment: Stating "matrix multiplication is linear in each slot" is shorthand for saying that we have both $X(aY) = a(XY)$ and $X(Y_1 + Y_2) = XY_1 + XY_2$, as well as the corresponding conditions on the first slot.  In other words, you have assumed the statement that we are trying to prove (and a little bit more).